# UISegmentedControl event does not work properly

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

I am currently working with a UISegmentedControl with 2 selections here. I have already defined it in -(void)viewDidLoad:

```
_segmentSelector = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:_selectorItems];
_segmentSelector.frame = CGRectMake(40, 356, 200, 43);
_segmentSelector.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled;
_segmentSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = 0; 
[_segmentSelector addTarget:self  
                     action:@selector(selectorValueChanged)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

The action for `@selector(selectorValueChanged)` is as following:

```
 - (void)selectorValueChanged
 {
     if(_segmentSelector.selectedSegmentIndex=1)
     {

     }
     if(_segmentSelector.selectedSegmentIndex=0)
     {

     }
 }
```

My problem is, that when i run a simulation and clicked on one button, then attempted to click another button, the SegmentedControl does not respond. It stays on the selection and refuses to accept another tap/click/whatever action i ordered it to. What is wrong with it?

Comment: If my answer helped, could you please "accept" it by clicking on the check mark outline to the left of the answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In `selectorValueChanged`, you assign new values to the selected segment index:

```
if (_segmentSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = 1)
```

Your probably mean

```
if (_segmentSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
```